# Wiring properties file with spring - expanding environment variables

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

I have a .properties file that I"m reading with a Spring @Component,

```
@Value("${webapp.external_data_source_root_path}")
private String mExternalDataSourceRootPath;
```

The .properties file has:

```
webapp.external_data_source_root_path=[user.home]\/my_path\/
```

What i'm trying to do is to have it replace `[user.home]` with the system environment variable value for user.home. I tried changing brackets to curly braces, adding '$', etc, but it doesn't ever seem to expand. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If I can recall correctly, the syntax is `{user.home}`.

Comment: Already tried that. Doesn't work, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what I need is:

```
webapp.destination_data_root_path=${user.home}\/my_path\/
```

I thought I had tried the ${zzz} pattern, but perhaps I had a typo.